# pointer to function in a struct in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need to create a struct which contains 1 int, 2 char, 1 float and (I write the lines from the exercise): "two pointers on functions for reading data `void (read*)(student*st)` and one pointer for displaying data `void (write*)(student*st)` "

I just don't understand the sentence. I know the syntax for a pointer to function in C. I don't get what `read*` and `write*` are. If it was `*read` and `*write` then in would be the pointer variable name to a function and `(student*st)` is the parameter, a pointer to struct.

Also, in the exercise appear that the program is about ANSI C but also it asks me to use cin to read the number of students and to allocate memory using new for an array of students.

This is how I started.

```
struct student {
    int idNumber;
    char name[100];
    char gender[20];
    float mark;
    ??
};
```

Comment: " I don't get what `read*` and `write*` are" - I'm afraid this is invalid syntax. The pointers should look like `void (*read)(student*)`.

Comment: `void (read*)(student*st)` seems like a typo as you said. It should be `void (*read)(student*st)`. And being asked to use `cin` in C code doesn't make sense. Ask your instructor.

Comment: there is a nice explanation in the approved answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: Yes, your instructions appear to have a typo. I suggest you ask your instructor or a TA to clarify.

Comment: If the exercise says `void (read*)(student*st)`, it has a bug. Thats not legal C syntax. As you actually more or less write in the question, the correct syntax is `void (*read)(student*st)`

Comment: The languages C and C++ are different languages. The global object [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) only exists in C++. The corresponding stream in C is [`stdin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams) and exists also in C++, because C++ is mostly compatible with C. Also, the operator `new` only exists in C++, not C. The corresponding function in C is `malloc`.

Comment: "Also, in the exercise appear that the program is about ANSI C" -- Since C++ ist mostly compatible with C, if a program looks like C, it is most likely also a valid C++ program. If it uses `std::cin` and `new`, that it is only a valid C++ program. So if the exercise doesn't explicitly claim to be a C program, you should assume that it is a C++ program.

Comment: If you don't know what language you have to use for the assignment, ask your professor. We surely don't know.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with the following code sample? I only add one function pointer (`func_print`), but the code should be self explanatory:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    int idNumber;
    char name[100];
    char gender[20];
    float mark;
    void (*func_print)(struct student *);
};

void print(struct student *s)
{
    printf("ID    : %d\n", s->idNumber);
    printf("Name  : %s\n", s->name);
    printf("Gender: %s\n", s->gender);
    printf("Mark  : %f\n", s->mark);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct student foo = { 0, "John Doe", "Male", 1.0, &print};
    
    foo.func_print(&foo);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./foo
ID    : 0
Name  : John Doe
Gender: Male
Mark  : 1.000000
$
```

This technique is very often used in various C programs. (You have added the **C** tag, none **C++** tag. So far other members wrote, `std::cin` and `new` are **C++** only.)

Linux device driver structure [(device_driver)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/device/driver.h) as real world example:

```
struct device_driver {
    const char      *name;
    struct bus_type     *bus;

    struct module       *owner;
    const char      *mod_name;  /* used for built-in modules */

    bool suppress_bind_attrs;   /* disables bind/unbind via sysfs */
    enum probe_type probe_type;

    const struct of_device_id   *of_match_table;
    const struct acpi_device_id *acpi_match_table;

    int (*probe) (struct device *dev);
    void (*sync_state)(struct device *dev);
    int (*remove) (struct device *dev);
    void (*shutdown) (struct device *dev);
    int (*suspend) (struct device *dev, pm_message_t state);
    int (*resume) (struct device *dev);
    const struct attribute_group **groups;
    const struct attribute_group **dev_groups;

    const struct dev_pm_ops *pm;
    void (*coredump) (struct device *dev);

    struct driver_private *p;
};
```